# how do i populated field from previous entry sharepoint infopath 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

In my SharePoint there are couple of fields like  client address, client title etc. which should be auto populated based on another field called RFS number if the user has already entered the details of the same before in the same list.

I know how to add field from another list based on condition. But how do i do it for the same list.

Comment: Did you get it working? Did my answer helps you in it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill the details to some of the controls based on another field called RFS number (In your case). Than Use [Rules](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/infopath-basics-understanding-rules-infopath.htm) and Filters on the [secondary data source](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/infopath-basics-main-secondary-data-source.htm) to retrieve information from the secondary data source and fill fields on the form with data related to the selected item in the RFS number field.

Kindly refer below article.

[Auto-fill fields in InfoPath from a drop-down list box selection and secondary data source](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2003/autofill-fields-infopath-dropdown-selection-secondary-data-source.htm)

**Note:-**

1. In this reference link they used dropdown & did the same.
2. In your case you can use same data source instead of another data source.

Comment: Have you tried above solution? Please let me know if you need help/more information.